Tensor product in the space of operators.
I have to solve the following question, but I’m a little bit confused in some details.
Let $V$ be a complex vector space of finite dimension $n$ and let $L(V)$ be
the space of linear operators from $V$ to $V$. Define the map: $c: L(V) \otimes L(V) \to L(V) $ as $c(S \otimes T):= S \circ T$ on the pure tensors $S \otimes T$ . Prove that $c$ is linear.
My question is: What does it mean to be linear in this context?

Do you mean the map should be $L(V) \otimes L(V) \to L(V) \otimes L(V)$? Also, this is a strange formulation as you only define the map on tensors of the form $S \otimes T$. Are you sure it's "Prove that $c$ is linear" and not "Prove that there exists a linear map $c$"?

What you have written is the effect of the identity map on $L(V) \otimes L(V)$, so an error has probably been made in the way you wrote the question. Did you perhaps mean $c(S \otimes T) = T \otimes S$ on all elementary tensors, or something else not as trivial as what the identity map would do?

Excuse, $c(S \otimes T)=S \circ T$ ins the pure tensors $S \otimes T$.

You need to specify the codomain of $c$. Also please include your own thoughts and read the definition of a linear map and of a tensor product.

Hi Martin. I understand both definitions. If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two arbitrary elements of $L(V) \otimes L(V)$ what would be $v_1+v_2?$

The gist of it is that linear functions defined on $L(V)\otimes L(V)$ are the same thing as bilinear functions defined on $L(V)\times L(V)$.
In your case, the function $L(V)\times L(V) \to L(V)$ given by $(S,T)\mapsto S\circ T$ is bilinear, since
$$(S_1+\lambda S_2)\circ T = S_1\circ T + \lambda S_2\circ T\quad\mbox{and} \quad S\times (T_1+\lambda T_2) = S\circ T_1 + \lambda S\circ T_2$$for all $S,S_1,S_2,T,T_1,T_2\in L(V)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$; the second relation relies on linearity of $S$. The universal property of tensor products says that there exists a unique linear map $L(V)\otimes L(V) \to L(V)$ which sends $S\otimes T$ to $S\circ T$ for all $T,S\in L(V)$.
The point here is that just saying that $c(S\otimes T) = S\circ T$ is not sufficient to define your mapping $c$, since elements of $L(V)\otimes L(V)$ are not necessarily of the form $S\otimes T$ for some $S,T\in L(V)$, but instead sums of terms of this form. Since there is, in general, more than one way to represent a given element of $L(V)\otimes L(V)$ (e.g. $(\lambda S)\otimes T = S\otimes (\lambda T)$), we need the universal property to make sure that $c$ is well-defined. And it gives us linearity of $c$ for free.
